# Apply a function to specific numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, function

So, I am trying to apply a function called E_CUTOFF to a specific array of values of height h (shape(28,0), the problem is that this function depends on another array called Ec, which shape is (81,0), so since the size of the arrays do not match, I am not able to apply the function. What I can do is just apply the function to every individual value of h, but, is there any method to apply this function to the whole array in just one run?

I will leave the code of my idea here, I would really appreciate help, thank you! :)

```
def E_CUTOFF(h, E, Ec):
    h=np.arange(500,1060, 20)
    E_cutoff = np.interp(threshold, get_I2(Ec, E, 0.652, h), Ec)
    return('E_cutoff', E_cutoff)

E_CUTOFF(E,Ec)
```

Comment: Check out the idea of broadcasting; its supported by numpy

Comment: Thank you! I will check it